# Plot the Total Drag Fd

Tags: plotting

[image]

Hi. I'm trying to do part b. The min drag that I have is 0.006U^2+1.5833(W^2/U^2).

Comment: I've tried 12000 <= w <= 20000
n = length (w)
for i = 1 : n
u (i) = (263.8833*w (i)^2)^(1/4)
fd (i) = 0.006*u (i)^2 + 1.5833*(w (i)/u (i))^2
Plot[u, fd]

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Please edit your question and add the WL code you have tried. The code in your comment is not valid WL code.

Comment: The one i tried was Plot[0.006U^2+1.5833(W^2/U^2){x,0,580}]

Comment: There are two independent variables `U` and `W` so you will have to use `ContourPlot` or some other way to visualize the function. The range argument to `Plot` has to use the same symbol as the independent variables. Try `ContourPlot[0.006 u^2 + 1.5833 (w^2/u^2), {u, 0, 580}, {w, 12000, 20000}]`.

Comment: It looks really strange with multiple lines and different colors

Comment: Learn about [contour plots](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/thinking-about-multivariable-function/visualizing-scalar-valued-functions/v/contour-plots). You can also try `Plot3D[0.006 u^2 + 1.5833 (w^2/u^2), {u, 100, 1000}, {w, 12000, 20000}, PlotRange -> All]`. The function has a singularity at `u = 0`, so I changed the range of `u` to `100, 1000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can probably find your answer using a parametric plot.

```
(* Create the function *)
fd[u_, w_, sigma_ : 0.6] := 0.01 sigma u^2 + 0.95/sigma (w/u)^2
(* Minimum is at fd'\[Equal]0, which turns out to be a simple \
function of w *)
D[fd[u, w], u]
(* Solve fd'\[Equal]0, inspection indicates Last answer is real *)
soln = Last@Solve[D[fd[u, w], u] == 0, u]
(* Make a function out of that *)
u[w_] := u /. soln
(* Visualize sensitivity *)
ParametricPlot[{u[w], fd[uf[w], w]}, {w, 12000, 20000}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"U", "FD"}]
```

[image]